# How to make displayed output look as though it's being typed?

Tags: python

How I can make my Python program look like it is typing? All answers that work are helpful, and also this program works perfectly fine but I just want it to type letter by letter. Here is the program:

```
Firstname = input("what is your first name: ")
Lastname = input("what is your last name: ")

if Firstname == 'stewart' and Lastname == 'russell':
    print("Stewart, i am really sorry for how much i have been annoying you, and I promise that i will stop. Infact i will make it a new years resolution to stop annoying you. and please help me acchive that goal also if i stop annoying you, will you stop  annoyiing me?")
    ansewr = input("do you exept my appoligy? ")
    if ansewr == 'yes':
        print("yay! now time to help me stop annoying you.")
    else:
        print("ok, guess i will have to try on my own. :(")
else:
    print("please check that you spelled your name with no capitals")
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: I'm unsure what the problem is

Comment: You can print without putting a newline with `print("something", end='')`. Maybe that helps you get started?

Comment: So instead of printing instantly, you want it to imitate typing the string by printing it character-by-character/ word-by-word?

Comment: Also, you want to open/reopen stdout unbuffered (`python -u` from the commandline)

Comment: Off-topic: Suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to simply print out each character individually with a small delay between print statements. Something like this:

```py
import time

def type_print(content):
    for letter in content:
        print(letter, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(.5)   # block program execution for .5 seconds (500 milliseconds)
```

Comment: So Where would I put this in my code?

Comment: Couple of errors there, including a syntax error.

Comment: @aneroid Oops thats embarrasing, all should be fixed.

Comment: @SterlingRussell Ideally above the rest of your code and call it as you would a normal funciotn (eg `type_print(Firstname)`)